# How to clear form field - Formik

Tags: javascript, formik

I have following Formik component.

I would like to clear the field whenever I click 'Clear filters' button. I figured out something like that, but this does not works as I expected. This clear the fields but user is still able to see field value. How should I implement this to clear formik value and user will not see value in form

```js
const Form = () => {

  const handleClearFilters = (resetForm, values) => {
    console.log(values)
    resetForm();
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        dog: '',
      }}
      onSubmit={() => {
        // onsubmit functionality
      }}
    >
      {({resetForm, values}) => (
        <FormikForm>
          <Field value={values.dog} name="dog" type="text" as={SearchInput} />
          <Styled.ButtonsWrapper>
            <Styled.Button onClick={() => handleClearFilters(resetForm, values)} kind='secondary'>Clear filters</Styled.Button>
            <Styled.Button type='submit'>Search</Styled.Button>
          </Styled.ButtonsWrapper>
        </FormikForm>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

SearchInput

```js
const SearchInput = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const [, , helpers] = useField(name);
  const { setValue } = helpers;

  const handleChange = (value: string | null) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <Styled.Wrapper>
      <Styled.Input
        {...props}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Search for job name"
        searchType={'primary'}
      />
    </Styled.Wrapper>
  );
};

export default SearchInput;
```

Comment: Try `resetForm({values: ''});`

Comment: @kiranvj Yes this clear the values from formik but I still see this value in form field as a user

Comment: @kiranvj I think the problem may cause UI library. As={SearchInput} - it is UI component. When I try to remove 'as' and use built Field component - clear form ability works

Comment: @kiranvj I edited post. Something like that? value={values.dog}?

Comment: @kiranvj I did ;)

Comment: Try this working version - https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-with-custom-field-component-forked-80c1mk?file=/src/MyForm.jsx:895-943

Comment: @kiranvj Could you share this code on something else? Codesandbox does not works for me ;/ Mac problem